# Calling an async task from a button click in a listitem inside of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

My app has a NavigationDrawer activity that swaps fragments based on the selection. One of these fragments contains a listview with several buttons. The listview items themselves are not selectable, but the I need to handle the button clicks, which I'm able to do capture successfully in my custom adapter.

Here is my issue: some button clicks need to trigger an async task to call REST api urls. I'm not sure how to do this. I tried calling a static method on my fragment that would instantiate an instance of a private class (extends AsyncTask), but that won't work. I thought about making a private class inside my custom adapter that extends from AsyncTask, but that doesn't feel right. What's the proper way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be different then Async tasks from anywhere else. Take a look at the documentation

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Create a class for your task

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

Then create an instance of it in your onClick event

```
 new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Comment: If this private class is part of my custom adapter, is that considered "poor design"? Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd say it's pretty highly dependent on what you want to do. In my current project, I'm using an async task to get an image from a URL, that I use all over the app. Now since this is the same functionality everywhere, I have it in my main activity, as a static class. I also have another, more general task that is used to call different API's on my server. With this one, I use it in a lot different places, but I have implemented an interface with it, such that I can override the onPostExecute to do whatever I need to with that data. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class which extends Asynctask

```
public class webservice extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{

private Context c;


public webservice(int mode)
{

}


public void set_context(Context c)
{this.c =c;

}


public void call_webservice_login() 
{
// procedure to call webservice etc...



}




@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     call_webservice_login();
    return 0;
}




protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
   //update your UI, etc
}


protected void onPreExecute(){ 
       super.onPreExecute();
            pgd = new ProgressDialog(c);
            pgd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pgd.show();    
    }


protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onPostExecute(result);


}

}
```

you can call it like this.

```
webservice wb1 = new webservice(1);
            //wb1.set_context(this);
            wb1.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a fully functional `ListView`, you need an **Adapter**.

So, the best approach here would be:

1. In the Adapter constructor, declare a `OnClickListener` that calls the AsyncTask.
2. In the `getView()`method of your Adapter, add the listener to the buttons that must perform any action: `myButton.setOnClickListener(mListener)`.
3. If you need any special parameters for different buttons, I recommend adding some flag or object using `myView.setTag(Object)` to the button in the `getView()` method. The listener receives a `View` parameter when called, which is the clicked view. Simply use `view.getTag()` in your listener code to figure which button was pressed.